# Tree Widget Alignment

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

Does anybody know how could i align the tree view like that one of the comboboxes?

[How it looks and how i would like to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6av1.jpg)

```
        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree_view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(root_path))
        self.tree_view.hideColumn(1)
        self.tree_view.setColumnWidth(0,300)
        self.tree_view.setFixedSize(200,250)

        
        self.model.setNameFilters(["*.py"])
        self.model.setNameFilterDisables(False)
        
        


    def create_layouts(self):
        
        attr_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        attr_layout.addWidget(self.project_combobox)
        attr_layout.addWidget(self.assets_combobox)
        attr_layout.addWidget(self.path_combobox)
        attr_layout.addWidget(self.model_combobox)
        attr_layout.addWidget(self.character_combobox)
        attr_layout.addWidget(self.tree_view)
        attr_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
```

Comment: do you want to align the text ?

Comment: No, I would like to align the tree view with the comboboxes on the same line. You can see this on the photo.

Comment: `addWidget(widget, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)` for all widgets.